# Check all objects inside collection should have length greater than 0

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, break

I have a code snippet like this

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(target.getSpecifications())) {
            for (final SpecificationData data : target.getSpecifications()) {
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data.getModelName())) {
                    productLinks.add(DETAILS);
                    break;
                } else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data.getModelNumber())) {
                    productLinks.add(DETAILS);
                    break;
                } else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data.getMaterial())) {
                    productLinks.add(DETAILS);
                    break;
                } else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data.getColour())) {
                    productLinks.add(DETAILS);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I am iterating a collection and doing a check in order to populate the link "details" in front end. The idea is that I need to populate this link at least one of the attribute length inside current object should be > 0. Because of the fact, I have used so many break statement, this snippet is failing in sonar build process

1. What do I need?  I request you guys to share me the simplest version of the above code or refactored code  using latest JDK and yes we are using JDK 11 and I am not pretty sure about the methods that I need to use for this kind of check.
2. If there is no other alternatives how to overcome this "Loops should not contain more than a single "break" or "continue" statement" sonar issue.

Appreciate your time and effort on this.

Comment: Merge all if-else as single if with or condition

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks I tried your solution as well.I have used your solution for another logic.Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution could be just to join multiple `if` statements into one though it may not be helpful against Sonar rules :)

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(target.getSpecifications())) {
    for (final SpecificationData data : target.getSpecifications()) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data.getModelName())
            || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data.getModelNumber())
            || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data.getMaterial())
            || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data.getColour())
        ) {
            productLinks.add(DETAILS);
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

However, you may use stream operations such as `filter` and `findFirst` like this without any for loop and `break` statements:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(target.getSpecifications())) {
    target.getSpecifications().stream()
        .filter(x ->
            Stream.of(x.getModelName(), x.getModelNumber(), x.getMaterial(), x.getColour())
                  .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
                  .findFirst()
                  .isPresent()
        )
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(x -> productLinks.add(DETAILS));
}
```

**UPDATE**

For this specific case it is also possible to use `flatMap` to detect any first non-empty property and perform an action:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(target.getSpecifications())) {
    target.getSpecifications().stream()
        .flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x.getModelName(), x.getModelNumber(), x.getMaterial(), x.getColour()))
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(x -> productLinks.add(DETAILS));
}
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/13279831/alex-rudenko Thanks a lot for your help and yes it worked for me and passed the sonar stuff as well.Appreciate your quick help on this.